# Contador usando PySimpleGui ou TkInter

Tags: python, tkinter

Precisava desenvolver um contador para contar o número de rounds de uma programação que estou desenvolvendo. Eu sei criar uma janela normalmente em ambos os módulos, mas não consigo pensar em como fazer esse contador dentro dessa janela. Ela está a base de rounds, por exemplo, ele fez o primeiro round no 0, assim que completar o primeiro round, adicionar mais 1+. Se puderem me ajudar, ficarei grato...

```
import pyautogui
import time
import sys
from time import sleep
from threading import Timer
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
driver.fullscreen_window()
time.sleep(30)

def whatBot():
   #Seleciona o grupo
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pane-side']/div[1]/div/div/div[11]/div/div/div/div[2]").click()
   #Seleciona os três pontinhos
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main']/header/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/span").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='app']/div[1]/span[4]/div/ul/div/div/li[2]/div[1]").click()
   #pyautogui.click(1402, 153, duration= 0.5)
   pyautogui.click(711, 970, duration= 0.2)
   #1495, 187
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main']/span[2]/div[1]/button[5]").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='app']/div[1]/span[2]/div[1]/span/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/label/div").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='app']/div[1]/span[2]/div[1]/span/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/label/div/div[2]").send_keys('SP -')
   pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100)
   pyautogui.click(792, 315)
   time.sleep(3)
   pyautogui.hotkey('end')
   time.sleep(3)
   pyautogui.click(928, 897)
   pyautogui.click(928, 830)
   pyautogui.click(928, 757)
   pyautogui.click(928, 687)
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='app']/div[1]/span[2]/div[1]/span/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/span/div/div/div/span").click()
  # pyautogui.click(928, 575, duration= -0.5)
  # pyautogui.click(928, 505, duration= -0.5)
  # pyautogui.click(928, 428, duration= -0.5)
  # pyautogui.click(928, 352, duration= -0.5)
  # pyautogui.click(928, 290, duration= -0.5)
  # pyautogui.moveTo(835, 565, duration= 0.5)
  # pyautogui.click(835, 565)
tempo = 0
while tempo != 821:
    t = Timer(1, whatBot)
    t.start()
    sleep(15)
    tempo += 1
```

Comment: Me ajude a entender, o que é o seu round? Seria o valor salvo na variável `tempo`? O que você quer é criar um Label mostrando esse valor?

Comment: Meu round, seria quantas vezes essa função whatBot foi repetida, e precisaria criar uma label para exibir essa quantidade. E sim, seria o valor salvo na variável `tempo`

Comment: Você quer criar uma interface gráfica somente para exibir a quantidade que a função foi executada?

Comment: Exato Felipe. Preciso que ela me mostre visualmente quantas vezes essa função foi executada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muito bem, como você disse que ode ser tkinter vou ensinar a fazer uma interface simples no tkinter somente para exibir a variável tempo.

Primeiro importe o tkinter, crie a janela principal:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
```

agora crie um label com o texto dizendo o número de rounds, que no início é zero, e coloque na janela principal:

```
label = tk.Label(root, text='rounds: 0')
label.pack()
```

a janela principal não fica aberta, ela precisa de um loop para permanecer atualizando. Normalmente isso é feito com o `mainloop()`, mas como você está dentro de um loop while, vc pode usar o método update(). Mas antes do update tudo que você precisa fazer é atualiar o texto do label com o valor de tempo:

```
tempo = 0
while tempo != 821:
    t = Timer(1, whatBot)
    t.start()
    sleep(15)
    tempo += 1
    label['text'] = 'rounds: {}'.format(tempo)
    root.update()
```